# Is there a "null" controller for routes that do not need a controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I currently have several routes in my app that are very simple and I am wondering what to do with the controller.  For instance for this route:

```
   $routeProvider                   
      .when('/', {                
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',  
        controller: 'MainCtrl'   
      })
```

My controller is just:

```
angular.module('nightwalkerApp')
.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope) {     
  // nothing
})
```

Is there some way to define not having a controller when it is not necessary? Is the controller optional for the routeProvider?

Comment: just remove `controller: 'MainCtrl'` from `.when()` method

Comment: Yes.  But without need controller means we need ng-template to include the html file

Comment: @CharanCherry Will you just make that an answer so I can accept it as such?  I foolishly did not read the docs before posting and your comment *is* the answer.